# Is it possible to use a method argument as an array extension method

Tags: c#, arrays, methods, arguments

I am trying to pass an argument to a method, and then use that argument as a array extension method, but I am struggling.  My code is:

```
//create method
public static void BankChoice(string SearchItem)
{
    //declare variables
    double tempMin = 0;
    int minIndex = 0;

    //set a temporary double as the first index of array
    tempMin = Program.array_SH1[0].SearchItem;

    //start loop to go through whole array
    for (int y = 0; y <= array_SH1.Length; y++)
    {
        //if the temp double is bigger than the array item, 
        //make array item temp double
        if (tempMin > array_SH1[y].SearchItem)
        {
            tempMin = array_SH1[y].SearchItem;
            minIndex = y;
        }
    }
}
```

I would then call the code as:

```
BankChoice("OpenPrice")
```

However this doesn't work.  The compiler won't accept the string as the array extension and it just throws and error.
Is there anyway to fix this without having to do it longhand, and create a method for all variations of SearchItem

Thanks

Comment: No, you can't do that. What you need to research is how to use reflection to accomplish this.

Comment: Side note: your sample does not show syntax that resembles calling extension method anywhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is to supply a delegate:

```
public static void BankChoice(Func<ArrayValueType, double> searchBy)
{
    //...
    // use the delegate to evaluate the result for each time you need to get the value from an item in your array.
    tempMin = searchBy(Program.array_SH1[0]);
    //...
}
```

Where `ArrayValueType` is the type of object in your array. Then you call it with

```
BankChoice(x => x.OpenPrice);
```

This will allow you to specify a property to search on, and it will be done in a type safe manner. The only restriction at the moment is that the property is convertible to a `double`. It's possible to get around that for properties of a generic type, and there are various ways to do that depending on what your needs are.

Comment: While it is right approach, strictly speaking it does not satisfy "without ... create a method for all variations of SearchItem" as each lambda will be converted to local method by compiler (I seriously doubt so if OP actually mean to add such restriction).

Comment: Yeah it sounds like what he really wants is to be able to write an algorithm that takes a parameter which lets him specify which property to apply the algorithm to, to avoid having to rewrite the entire algorithm for each desired property to search on.